# Has a source of vitamin C ever been successfully grown in space?

Tags: health, food, nutrition

Growing one's own food has long been a goal of space exploration.  It has the potential to reduce the amount of mass needed for long-term missions.  Food has been experimentally grown and eaten on the Space Shuttle, International Space Station, and other programs.

One of the problems of long missions during the age of sail was scurvy, a deficiency of vitamin C.  To this end, British ships carried limes for the sailors' diets.  **Have any plants which provide vitamin C** (such as citrus fruit or tomatoes) **been grown in space?**

Related:

- [Where in the solar system can a person safely get enough sun to make vitamin D?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/5821/26446)
- [Mass of food per astronaut per year for an extended deep space excursion?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24044/26446)
- [Are there any vegetarian astronauts?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36878/26446)

Comment: If you want to eat something with much vitamin C, you should consider eating broccoli, kale or brussels sprouts instead of citrus fruits.

Comment: Why grow plants actually? Vitamine C can be synthesized chemically or with bacteria https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitamin_C#Industrial_synthesis, and other vitamines with bacteria anyway https://www.intechopen.com/books/probiotics-and-prebiotics-in-human-nutrition-and-health/biosynthesis-of-vitamins-by-probiotic-bacteria

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plants_in_space - Greens like cabbage have some. But still... I can't find anything about citrus in space.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: If cabbage has been grown in space, then you have found an answer.  I believe *Brassica rapa* has been grown (to study growth; it's rather small for food), but not sure about *Brassica oleracia*.

Comment: I wonder if chili peppers have vitamin C; https://www.sciencealert.com/nasa-has-announced-the-first-fruit-they-want-to-grow-on-the-iss

Comment: @uhoh honestly some may prefer scurvy to scarfing chilli peppers.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn See [Why Astronauts Crave Tabasco Sauce](https://www.npr.org/sections/thesalt/2012/02/23/147294191/why-astronauts-crave-tabasco-sauce) and [There’s a Bottle of Sriracha Onboard the International Space Station](https://www.thedailymeal.com/eat/there-s-bottle-sriracha-onboard-international-space-station) and NASA's [Taste in Space](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/files/Taste-in-space-TLA-FINAL.pdf) "But….
When food seems to lose its flavor, astronauts usually ask for condiments, such as hot sauces, to give food some intensity of taste." and...

Comment: ...and [Astronauts crave spicy food in space — here's why](https://www.businessinsider.com/astronauts-crave-spicy-food-in-space-tabasco-why-2016-2) and the cool video [Sriracha in Space](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KrRWzk-OtKI) and [Why Astronauts Eat Irradiated Turkey Covered in Hot Sauce on Thanksgiving](https://www.inverse.com/article/8382-why-astronauts-eat-irradiated-turkey-covered-in-hot-sauce-on-thanksgiving) But you can put chilis in gelatin capsules if you're still adverse to the [nirvana-like experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirvana) of eating good chilis.

Comment: There have been some great ideas here (Uwe, Magic, uhoh), so how about **somebody writes an answer?**

Comment: I _highly_ doubt that any manned spacecraft (or any spacecraft, _period_) so far has had enough space, or anywhere close to the right growing conditions, to grow citrus fruit (citrus grow on _trees_, and often quite large, gangly trees at that, and require consistently hot, humid conditions [imagine what that would do to electronic equipment!] and consistently moist soil in order to produce fruit).  Even citrus grown indoors on Earth are difficult to persuade to produce fruit unless you have a greenhouse - never mind _in space_.  (Oh, and citrus trees are _also_ profusely and sharply thorny.)

Comment: @DrSheldon because I'm severely lacking in the biology knowledge department and by no means an expert on space, therefore it'd be irresponsible for me to answer ;).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes; NASA selected bok choy, aka "Chinese cabbage", for one of their recent garden experiments, quite possibly because of its high vitamin c content (45mg, half of your daily recommended dose, per 100g).

The mission launched in 2014, and as far as I'm aware was a success but I haven't tracked down the specific paper recounting the experiment, if anyone's feeling keen to do a journal search.

Comment: Welcome to *Space*, and nice answer!  If you later find the paper, please add the reference to this answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Compared to other potential sources of vitamin C, bok choy has the additional advantages of (1) fits in smaller spaces, (2) grows rapidly, (3) no flowering -- hence no pollen -- required, and (4) the whole plant is edible (no waste).

Comment: “Chinese cabbage grown on the ISS developed leaf chlorosis, necrosis, and uneven growth despite its high rank in ground-based screenings. Troubleshooting studies concluded elevated CO2 concentrations caused plant-stress symptoms. These findings indicate the importance of mimicking controllable ISS-like conditions during ground-based screenings.”. http://dx.doi.org//10.1016/j.lssr.2020.07.007